# set field for docs in one collection based on ref to another collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have `todo` schema and `actions` schema.  Each `todo` is made up of `actions`.  My `todos` already have a field for 'subject'.

Question: How do I update the actions so that their 'subject' field equals a given 'subject' field fro the referenced `todo`?

```js
const todo = new Schema({
  subject: String,
  actions: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Action' },


})
```

```js
const action = new Schema({
  action: String ,
  todoID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Todo' },
  subject: String //needs to be populated

})
```

*I want to avoid doing something like this:
Action.find().forEach(action=>{
todo.findByID(action.todoID)
.then(`yadda yadda`)
.catch(`not what I want to do`)
})

I feel like there is an aggregation solution but I cant figure this out.

Thank you.